# Entity Framework Filter "Expression<Func<T, bool>>"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to create a filter method for Entity framework List and understand better the

`Expression<Func<...`

I have a Test Function like this.

```
public IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> src, Expression<Func<T, bool>> pred)
{
    return src.AsQueryable().Where(pred);
}
```

and if I do this:

```
context.Table.Filter(e => e.ID < 500);
```

or this:

```
context.Table.Filter(e => e.SubTable.Where(et => et.ID < 500).Count() > 0 && e.ID < 500);
```

it all works well.

But if I do this:

```
context.Table.Filter(e => e.SubTable.Filter(et => et.ID < 500).Count() > 0 && e.ID < 500);
```

or this:

```
context.Table.Where(e => e.SubTable.Filter(et => et.ID < 500).Count() > 0 && e.ID < 500);
```

I receive one error.
`LINQ to Entities does not recognise the method ...Filter...`

Why does it work in one case and not in the other? What should I change in the filter to make it work with related tables?
I prefer to stay away from other external libraries as what I want is to learn how it works and be able to use it in any scenario in future.

In the first two cases, the filter runs in the database correctly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Jon and Tim already explained why it doesn't work.

Assuming that the filter code inside `Filter` is not trivial, you could change `Filter` so that it returns an expression EF can translate.

Let's assume you have this code:

```
context.Table.Where(x => x.Name.Length > 500);
```

You can now create a method the returns this expression:

```
Expression<Func<YourEntity, bool>> FilterByNameLength(int length)
{
    return x => x.Name.Length > length;
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
context.Table.Where(FilterByNameLength(500));
```

The expression you build inside `FilterByNameLength` can be arbitrarily complex as long as you could pass it directly to `Where`.

Comment: by lots of reading and trial and error I suspected this was the only way. will it work cases like context.Table.Where(e => e.subTable.Any(MyFilter()));

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid: No, it won't. The result of this method needs to be passed to the outermost `Where`, because every expression that you pass to the outermost `Where` isn't actually executed but interpreted.

Comment: I made a test and this works var filter = MyFilter(); context.Table.Where(e => e.subTable.AsQueryable().Any(filter));

Comment: @Pedro: Interesting. EF seems to evaluate it, because from the POV of the expression it is a constant. Good find.

Answer (score 14):

It's useful to understand the difference between [`Expression<Func<>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) and [`Func<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

An `Expression` `e => e.ID < 500` stores the info about that expression: that there's a `T` `e`, that you're accessing the property `ID`, calling the `<` operator with the `int` value `500`. When EF looks at that, it might turn it into something like `[SomeTable].[ID] < 500`.

A `Func` `e => e.ID < 500` is a method equivalent to:

```
static bool MyMethod(T e) { return e.ID < 500; }
```

It is compiled as IL code that does this; it's not designed to be 'reconstituted' into a SQL query or anything else, only run.

When EF takes your `Expression`, it must understand every piece of it, because it uses that to build a SQL query. It is programmed to know what the existing `Where` method means. It does not know what your `Filter` method means, even though it's a trivial method, so it just gives up.

Answer (score 9):

> Why it works in one case and not in the adder?

Because EF doesn't really "know" about your `Filter` method. It has no understanding of what it's meant to do, so it doesn't know how to translate it into SQL. Compare that with `Where` etc, which it *does* understand.

The version where you call it *directly* on the initial table works because that way you don't end up with an expression tree containing a call to `Filter` - it just calls `Filter` directly, which in turn *does* build up a query... but one which EF understands.

I'd be very surprised if you could work out a way of getting your `Filter` method to work within an EF query... but you've already said that using `Where` works anyway, so why use `Filter` at all? I'd use the `Where` version - or better yet, use the `Any` overload which takes a predicate:

```
context.Table.Filter(e => e.SubTable.Any(et => et.ID < 500) && e.ID < 500);
```

Comment: is there any way it can be changed to end up with one expression tree witch dose not include the method name?

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid: Not easily. You could write a method which rewrote the expression tree and created a new query based on that, but it's not clear why you'd want to do so, and it would be tricky.

Comment: as for the use of Where its just for easy of test in real environment it will be much more complex.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid: Well without knowing what you're really *trying* to achieve, it's hard to help you - but basically you'll have a hard time trying to do anything quite like this.

Comment: I know this is an old thread and all, but digging about EF made me think that this method won't work because it is casting the tables as IEnumerable, and then using AsQueryable, which will make a query on that IEnumerable instead of creating the desired SQL query. Wouldn't it work if the filter method src parameter was IQueryable<T>?

Comment: @JohniMichels: Yes, although at that point it's pretty pointless too :)