# Using Func<> in Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following Entity Framework query:

```
Func<Company, bool> filter;
if (officeId != 0)
    filter = company => !company.IsDeleted && company.OfficeCompanies.Any(c => c.OfficeId == officeId);
else
    filter = company => !company.IsDeleted;

var companies = from c in Repository.Query<Company>()
                where filter(c) &&
                    (relationshipTypes.Count() == 0 || relationshipTypes.Any(r => r == c.TypeEnumIndex)) &&
                    c.Description.Contains(term)
                orderby c.Description
                select new JqueryUiAutoCompleteItem
                {
                    label = c.Description,
                    value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.Id)
                };
```

It gives me the error:

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

If I remove the reference to `filter()` in the main body of the query, there is no error.

I understand the meaning of this error: I am using code that cannot be converted into SQL. But what is there about my `filter()` that cannot be converted to SQL?

Comment: You have to create it as in Expression. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool

Comment: @TyCobb: I tried that, but how can I call the filter expression from my query. I can't call it as I do above. The page you linked to uses the `.Where()` method instead of a LINQ query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to switch the `Func` to an `Expression`, then pass that expression to a `Where` directly in LINQ fluent syntax. I don't think there's a way to use the expression in query syntax.

```
Expression<Func<Company, bool>> filter; //<-- changed type
if (officeId != 0)
    filter = company => !company.IsDeleted && company.OfficeCompanies.Any(c => c.OfficeId == officeId);
else
    filter = company => !company.IsDeleted;

var companies = from c in Repository.Query<Company>().Where(filter) // <-- changed syntax
                where (relationshipTypes.Count() == 0 || relationshipTypes.Any(r => r == c.TypeEnumIndex)) &&
                    c.Description.Contains(term)
                orderby c.Description
                select new JqueryUiAutoCompleteItem
                {
                    label = c.Description,
                    value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.Id)
                };
```

Comment: Yes, it looks a little strange tagging on `.Where()` to a LINQ query, but it appears to work.