# Entity Framework date combination query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a list of `Apartments` where each `Apartment` has it's `ApartmentRooms`, where each `ApartmentRoom` has it's `DateBatches`. Each `DateBatch` has list of `Dates` which represents occupied dates (one record per taken date).

```
Apartment 1
 Room 1
    DateBatch
      1.5.2015
      2.5.2015
    DateBatch 2
      8.5.2015
      9.5.2015
 Room 2
    DateBatch
      5.5.2015
      6.5.2015
```

By this, you can see that this apartment has 2 rooms of which Room 1 is taken on following dates 1.5, 2.5, 8.5 and 9.5 and room 2 is occupied on 5.5 and 6.5.

User can enter a desired period of N days and X amount of consecutive days he wants to stay.

So for an example, user enters period from 1.5 to 15.5 and he wants to sleep 10 nights, I need to list all apartments where at least one of the apartment rooms is available for any of possible date combinations, which would be following in this case:

```
1.5-10.5
2.5-11.5
3.5-12.5
4.5-13.5
5.5-14.5
```

So far I have tried this, and it works only for first foreach iteration, because foreach concatenates query with AND criteria, not OR criteria, and I think this is a very bad approach to go.

```
 public static IQueryable<Apartment> QueryByPeriod(this IQueryable<Apartment> apartments, DateTime PeriodStart, DateTime PeriodEnd, int StayDuration)
 {
        var possibleDateRanges = new List<List<DateTime>>();

        //set all possible start dates for the desired period
        for (var i = PeriodStart; i <= PeriodEnd.AddDays(-StayDuration); i = i.AddDays(1))
        {
            List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

            foreach(var date in i.DateRange(i.AddDays(StayDuration-1)))
            {
                dates.Add(date);
            }

            possibleDateRanges.Add(dates);
        }

        //filter by date range
        //select apartment rooms where one of possible combinations is suitable for selected period
        foreach (var possibleDates in possibleDateRanges)
        {
            apartments = apartments.Where(m => m.ApartmentRooms
            .Any(g => g.OccupiedDatesBatches.Select(ob => ob.OccupiedDates).Any(od => od.Any(f => possibleDates.Contains(f.Date)))
            ) == false);
        }

        return apartments;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would not try to do everything with a sql statement to the database.  I would do some of the code with sql and the rest with c#.  I would first query database for rooms occupied between a start date and an end date which would be the earliest and latest date in the range the user wants a room.  Then use c# code to find which room are available for the period of days needed.

Comment: What does `Activity.Active` mean for room/date batch?

Comment: If it's something removed from the system, It's activity will be marked as Active = false. 
I'll remove it from the query to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure (does not require external packages) LINQ to Entities solution.

Start with determining the list of the possible start dates:

```
var startDates = Enumerable.Range(0, PeriodEnd.Subtract(PeriodStart).Days - StayDuration + 1)
    .Select(offset => PeriodStart.AddDays(offset))
    .ToList();
```

Then use the following query:

```
var availableApartments = apartments.Where(a => a.ApartmentRooms.Any(ar =>
    startDates.Any(startDate => !ar.OccupiedDatesBatches.Any(odb => 
        odb.OccupiedDates.Any(od => 
            od.Date >= startDate && od.Date < DbFunctions.AddDays(startDate, StayDuration))))));
```

The benefit of this solution is that it can easily be extended. The above query returns available apartments, but does not provide information which room is available and when - something you might need to provide to the user. Using the above approach, you can get that information like this:

```
public class AvailableApartmentInfo
{
    public Apartment Apartment { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

var availableApartmentInfo =
    from a in apartments
    from ar in a.ApartmentRooms
    from startDate in startDates
    where !ar.OccupiedDatesBatches.Any(odb => 
        odb.OccupiedDates.Any(od => 
            od.Date >= startDate && od.Date < DbFunctions.AddDays(startDate, StayDuration)))
    select new AvailableApartmentInfo { Apartment = a, Room = ar, StartDate = startDate };
```

Comment: This answer outperforms previous answer when the date range is higher and when there are more date combinations involved. Thank you. My guess is that `Any` beats `All` function from the previous answer?

Comment: Actually `Any` == `!All` and vice versa. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482467/entity-framework-where-clausule-with-any-and-all-use/36484562#36484562

Comment: I see, but In the answer above, we had ==`All`, so I am guessing that is the reason your query works faster

Comment: I didn't analyze the other answer, most probably the difference comes from how EF translates the query to SQL - my query generates something like SQL in memory table with constants, which also allows better SQL plan vs. parameters, i.e. eliminates so called parameter sniffing problem.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

To combine multiple conditions with OR, you can use (for example) LinqKit library. Install it via nuget, add `using LinqKit;` and then:

```
    public static IQueryable<Apartment> QueryByPeriod(this IQueryable<Apartment> apartments, DateTime PeriodStart, DateTime PeriodEnd, int StayDuration) {
        var possibleDateRanges = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>();
        // list all ranges, so for your example that would be:
        //1.5-10.5
        //2.5-11.5
        //3.5-12.5
        //4.5-13.5
        //5.5-14.5            
        var startDate = PeriodStart;
        while (startDate.AddDays(StayDuration - 1) < PeriodEnd) {
            possibleDateRanges.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(startDate, startDate.AddDays(StayDuration - 1)));
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
        }
        Expression<Func<Apartment, bool>> condition = null;
        foreach (var range in possibleDateRanges) {                
            Expression<Func<Apartment, bool>> rangeCondition = m => m.ApartmentRooms       
                // find rooms where ALL occupied dates are outside target interval             
                .Any(g => g.OccupiedDatesBatches.SelectMany(ob => ob.OccupiedDates).All(f => f.Date < range.Item1 || f.Date > range.Item2)
                );
            // concatenate with OR if necessary
            if (condition == null)
                condition = rangeCondition;
            else
                condition = condition.Or(rangeCondition);
        }
        if (condition == null)
            return apartments;
        // note AsExpandable here
        return apartments.AsExpandable().Where(condition);
    }
```

Note that I also modified your logic. Of course, this logic is perfect candidate for unit-testing, and if you are working on a serious project - you should definely test it using in-memory EF provider (or mocking) for different conditions.

Comment: I think there is something flawed with possible date ranges period. it ends with 14.5-18.5 as it's last record,

Comment: Nvm: found the issue.It should be `i <= (PeriodEnd - PeriodStart).TotalDays - StayDuration` . Let me test a bit, and i'll mark your answer as complete if all works ok :)

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood how you work with ranges. I thought user sets range for _start_ period (i.e. start between 1 and 5, stay for 10 days). Modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works like a charm now. Since you were first on the scene, and your code actually does the job, I will mark your answer as correct as soon as I can. If you have any ideas about performance increase, please do write :)

Comment: It depends on your perfomance requirements. Unless you have thousands of appartments, probably you should not worry too much about perfomance, because even full table scans would be fast anyway (but make some tests by inserting as much test data as you would expect in real use). If perfomance would not be enough - raw sql queries can come to the rescue. Long story short - test with expected amount of real data and see if it's fine or not.

Comment: I apologize for my premature promise. I will leave this topic open more a bit and wait for more answers.

Comment: @Robert sure, Ivan's answer is better so there is nothing wrong in unaccepting my answer and accepting his :)