# How To Use C# Linq Predicate with custom Extension Method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to write a C# Extension Method, that should take a Predicate and return IQueryable so i can reuse a complicated **Where Predicate**

Here is what i'm looking at

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> AddComplexWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, DBContext context, Func<T, string> PermissionKeyColumn)
    {
        return query.Where(pp => context.Permissions
            .Where(p => /*PermissionKeyColumn is in Permissions Table p.PermissionKey  ??????*/)
            .Where(p => true/* another complicated where*/).Any());
    }
```

usage will be

```
context.orders.AddComplexWhere(context,o=>o.permissionKey).ToList()..
```

this way i can keep reusing the where

Comment: what do you want the extension method to do?

Comment: append to where il update the answer

Comment: check - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: So what is the relation between `query` and `context.Permissions` . I can't find any. You're not using `pp` anywhere. Can you give an more complete example of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: the relation is the permissionKey its on the order and in the permission table

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>>
```

Here is example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AddComplexWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, DBContext context, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return query.Where(expression).Any());
    }
```

After this modification your code should just work:

```
context.orders.AddComplexWhere(context,o=>o.permissionKey == something).ToList()..
```

Comment: Can you use a Func in the Where clause, it needs a predicate

Comment: it's `Expression` of `Func` not Func. Predicate itself is used in `Find` functions.

Comment: but how do i filter based on the PermissionKey  from the added Permissions table ? if all i do is pass the Where i don't need it, i can just use Where. i need it to filter based on the PermissionKey  columns

Comment: this something needs to be from the added Permissions table added inside the AddComplexWhere method

Comment: it's EF so probably you have property of type Permission in your objects, is it right?

Comment: I can see Expression<Func> but that will compile to a Func, with string output here which is not a boolean, so how would that help in the Where clause

Comment: if you follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool 

there is also answer with 4ups - where is explanation of differences between Func and Expression of Func

Comment: @CMS if this is method to add another Where statements to IQuerable, it's even enough to have only one where. As soon as it is IQueryable it's just building the query until it's evaluated by ToList, ToArray ot anything like this.

Comment: great thanks, then OP need to supply Func<T,bool> compiled expression tree, which is not the case as of now