# LINQ to Entities custom method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

In my code I have:

```
context.TableA
            .Where(x =>
                x.Created >= startDate
                && context.TableB.RecordExists(x.Id, 1));
```

And RecordExists is defined like:

```
public static bool RecordExists(this IQueryable<TableB> entity, int entityId, int entityTypeId)
{
    return entity.Any(x => x.EntityId == entityId && x.EntityTypeId == entityTypeId);
}
```

The above call fails with

> NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Boolean RecordExists(System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TableB], Int32, Int32)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

But if I change query to:

```
 context.TableA
            .Where(x =>
                x.Created >= startDate
                && context.TableB.Any(p => p.EntityId == x.Id && p.EntityTypeId == 1));
```

It works just fine, is there a way to use this method in queries?

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to use Extension method in Linq to Entities, because EF not support this feature.

Comment: I think You can use `bool RecordExists<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, ...` instead ;).

Comment: @shA.t why would that work?

Comment: I don't say it would work!!, I said you can use a generic form at all ;).

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Expressions

**Expression definition**

```
public Expression<Func<TableA, bool>> RecordExists(IEnumerable<TableB> entities, int entityTypeId)
{
    return a => entities.Any(b => b.Id == a.EntityId && b.EntityTypeId == entityTypeId);
}
```

**Example**

```
return context.TableA
    .Where(x => x.Created >= startDate)
    .Where(RecordExists(context.TableB, 1));
```

[Entity Framework Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18338476/2203349)

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL uses "Expression Trees" to translate lambda expressions to sql expressions. So you can not use methods, only inline expressions. But you can use methods in Linq to collections. If you call `.ToList()` function first on `TableA` then you can call methods. But `.ToList()` function will first retrieve everything in memory and then filter it. So that is highly not recommended.

Comment: That's not an option, I'd rather go with solution 2 then