# How can I extract DbFunctions/SqlFunctions call into a resuable extension/method with EntityFramework 6.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have an application written using `C#` on the top of the ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. In addition, I am using EntityFramework 6.2 as an ORM to interact with my data.

I wrote the following join statement using Fluent LINQ

```
List<string> names = new List<string>{"", ....};
query = TopLevelQuery.Where(x => x.EndedAt.HasValue && x.StartedAt >= startedAt && x.EndedAt.Value <= endedAt)
                     .Join(UserService.QueryUniqueRecords(),
                     entry => entry.UserId,
                     rec => rec.UserId,
                     (entry, rec) => new { entry, rec })
                     .Where(result => result.entry.IsEqualDateOf(result.rec.DayOf) 
                         && names.Contains(result.rec.Name))
                     .Select(x => x.entry);
```

However, I get the following error during runtime

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'IsEqualDateOf', and
>   this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is my `IsEqualDateOf` extension method

```
public static class MyModelExtensions
{
    public static DateTime GetLocalDate(this MyModel entry)
    {
        var local = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", entry.UtcOffset, entry.StartedAt));

        return local.Value;
    }

    public static bool IsEqualDateOf(this MyModel entry, DateTime dateOf)
    {
        bool isEqual = entry.GetLocalDate().Equals(dateOf.Date);

        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

However, if I convert my LINQ expression to the following pseudo, it works as expected

```
query = TopLevelQuery.Where(x => x.EndedAt.HasValue && x.StartedAt >= startedAt && x.EndedAt.Value <= endedAt)
                     .Join(UserService.QueryUniqueRecords(),
                     entry => entry.UserId,
                     rec => rec.UserId,
                     (entry, rec) => new { entry, rec })
                     .Where(result => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(SqlFunctions.DateAdd("ss", entry.UtcOffset, entry.StartedAt)) == result.rec.DayOf 
                         && names.Contains(result.rec.Name))
                     .Select(x => x.entry);
```

But, I want to be able to reuse the same logic in multiple places within my project, which is why I want to extract it into some kind of extension or method.

How, can I extract the `DbFunctions` and `SqlFunctions` call into a reusable method in which can be used in LINQ before `AsEnumerable()` is called?

**UPDATED**

I also tried to extract the logic into lambda expression by adding the following code to `MyModel` class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime StartedAt { get; set; }
    public int UtcOffset { get; set; }
    // ...

    public Expression<Func<MyModel, bool>> IsDateOf(DateTime dayOf)
    {
        return p => p.StartedAt.AddSeconds(p.UtcOffset) == dayOf.Date;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to consume it like so

```
query = TopLevelQuery.Where(x => x.EndedAt.HasValue && x.StartedAt >= startedAt && x.EndedAt.Value <= endedAt)
                     .Join(UserService.QueryUniqueRecords(),
                     entry => entry.UserId,
                     rec => rec.UserId,
                     (entry, rec) => new { entry, rec })
                     .Where(result => result.entry.IsDateOf(result.rec.DayOf) 
                         && names.Contains(result.rec.Name))
                     .Select(x => x.entry);
```

But that throws the following syntax error when trying to consume it

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   '`Expression<Func<MyModel,bool>>`' and bool.

Moreover, I tried making the `IsDateOf` expression static and called it like so

```
query = TopLevelQuery.Where(x => x.EndedAt.HasValue && x.StartedAt >= startedAt && x.EndedAt.Value <= endedAt)
                     .Join(UserService.QueryUniqueRecords(),
                     entry => entry.UserId,
                     rec => rec.UserId,
                     (entry, rec) => new { entry, rec })
                     .Where(result => result.entry.Where(MyModel.IsDateOf(result.rec.DayOf))
                         && names.Contains(result.rec.Name))
                     .Select(x => x.entry);
```

But that gives me the following syntax error

> 'MyMode' does not contain a definition for `Where` and the best
>   extension method overload
>   `Queryable.Where<MyModel>IQueryable<MyModel>, Expression<Func<MyModel,
>   bool>>)` required a reciever of type IQueryable

Comment: AFAIK you have to make it a lambda expression instead of a method, something like `Expression<Func<Datetime, bool>>`, and it can't have a body.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool) for an example of what I mean.

Comment: @Amy I have actually attempted that. Please check my updated question.

Comment: You are calling a method that returns an expression.  You are not invoking the expression.

Comment: Why are you now trying to call `result.entry.Where`?  Get rid of that.

Comment: You now have, for some reason, `.Where(result => result.entry.Where(MyModel.IsDateOf(result.rec.DayOf))
                         && names.Contains(result.rec.Name))`  Change that to `.Where(result => MyModel.IsDateOf(result.entry, result.rec.DayOf) && names.Contains(result.rec.Name))`

Comment: Don't want to interrupt, but is there a reason why putting the expression that uses `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` and `SqlFunctions.DateAdd` into a function, and returning that expression, parameterized, wouldn't work? (I last used EF 6.1)

Comment: @AnnL. That works just fine too.  It does result in invoking a method and invoking the expression, which may look a little weird.  See my answer.

Comment: @MikeA I should have asked you this HOURS ago:  are you trying/expecting all of this stuff -- the join, the filtering, etc. -- to happen down in the data store? Or up in the app?

Comment: @AnnL. Yes. I am expecting this LINQ to get translated into SQL query.  It would have been much easier if it was in memory because I the AddSeconds would work after .ToList()

Comment: I'm temporarily deleting my answer, because I now think it's incorrect, and I don't want a million people marking me down tomorrow morning for being wrong. :)  I'll rejoin you tomorrow.

Comment: @MikeA Are you still having problems with this, or have you found a solution?

Comment: @MikeA I wanted to ask whether `UserService.QueryUniqueRecords()` and `TopLevelQuery` used not only the same entity framework classes, but the same instance of the database context?  I suspect if they aren't connected to the same context instance, it won't be possible to do the joining in the data store.

Comment: @AnnL. I have not found a solution. UserService.QueryUniqueRecords() and TopLevelQuery are both `IQueryable<>` and both are pointing at the same context,

Comment: If I get a chance, I will do some more work on this. I've become intrigued.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parameter from your method and make the expression accept two parameters:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyModel, DateTime, bool>> IsDateOf 
    = (MyModel p, DateTime d) => p.StartedAt.AddSeconds(p.UtcOffset) == d.Date;
```

Note I have made it a static field, not a method.  Then in your LINQ expression, you need to invoke it:

```
MyModel.IsDateOf(result.entry, result.rec.DayOf)
```

If you don't make it a field (or property), you have to first invoke the method to get the expression; then you need to invoke the expression:

```
MyModel.IsDateOf()(result.entry, result.rec.DayOf)
```

Which, in my opinion, looks weird.

Comment: Thank you! When calling `MyModel.IsDateOf(result.entry, result.rec.DayOf)` I get the following error `Non-invocable member 'MyModel.IsDateOf' cannot be used like a method.` Here is how I am calling it `(entry, rec) => new { entry, rec}).Where(result => MyModel.IsDateOf(result.entry, result.rec.DayOf) && names.Contains(result.rec.Name)).` Not sure what I am missing this time.

Comment: Can you tell me whether the overload of `Where` you're using is taking `Expression<>` objects as parameters, or actual `Func<>` objects?

Comment: I *think* that @Amy's answer is assuming that the `Where` overload you're using has a parameter of `Expression<Func<MyModel,bool>>`, but that other things in the call are forcing it to use the overload that takes plain `Func<MyModel, bool>`. That would cause it to object: it wants a method, a `Func<>`, and it's been given an `Expression<Func<>>`.

Comment: From what I can tell, `.Where(result => )` accepts `IQueryable<'a> IQueryable<'a>.Where<'a>(Expression<Func<a', bool>> predicts)` a' is new { MyModel entry, MyRecord rec}