# The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Entity>.Where(p => p.IsValid)' could not be translated in EF Core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

First of all I know about the breaking change in EF Core 3 as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

But Im still a bit confused as to why the following code doesnt work:

```
var posts = await _applicationDbContext.Posts
            .Include(p => p.Account)
            .Include(p => p.Recording)
            .Where(p => p.AccountId == accountId && p.Type == postType && p.IsValid)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Occured)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Throwing the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>       .Where(p => p.AccountId == __accountId_0 && (int)p.Type == (int)__postType_1 && p.IsValid)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Implementation of IsValid is as follows:

```
public bool IsValid => Status == PostStatus.Active && Recording.IsValid
public bool IsValid => Status == RecordingStatus.Active;
```

Now, if I change the query to:

```
var posts = await _applicationDbContext.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Account)
        .Include(p => p.Recording)
        .Where(p => p.AccountId == accountId && p.Type == postType && p.Status == PostStatus.Active && p.Recording.Status == RecordingStatus.Active)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.Occured)
        .ToListAsync();
```

It works and is converted to sql as expected. Naturally I could go with the second implementation but there are obvious advantages to having the IsValid implementation in one place. I also dont want to skip the IsValid check in the query in favour of doing it in memory later for obvious reasons. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you get.

Comment: @Progman There.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Filter "Expression<Func<T, bool>>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool)

Comment: In the first case EF Core has no idea what `IsValid` property getter does (could you just looking at the class w/o having the source code?), hence cannot translate it to SQL. So the only option for them is to evaluate it locally after creating an object, but this was removed in 3.0+.

Comment: Well, I guess for me it doesnt really make sense why you would want it this way. The class and its implementation is right there, you might as well make use of it. As for the second implementation, if I want to change the IsValid check I need to change in multiple places, dublicating code etc. Even by making a private method in the same class as the query gives the same error.

Comment: @FredrikEk That's why you have to use an `Expression` which EF can translate to an SQL statement. You can keep a variant of the `IsValid` property which still returns a boolean value which will consume the generated `Expression`, so you don't have code duplication.

Comment: @Progman yeah I just tested it and its an alright workaround. I will create a solution below and refer to your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think the EF guys could have done this differently but anyway from the comment above by Progman linking to [this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool) it is possible to derive a workaround looking something like:

```
public static Expression<Func<Post, bool>> IsValid => post => post.Status == PostStatus.Active && post.Recording.Status == RecordingStatus.Active;
```

And then call it like:

```
var posts = await _applicationDbContext.Posts
    .Include(p => p.Account)
    .Include(p => p.Recording)
    .Where(p => p.AccountId == accountId && p.Type == postType)
    .Where(Post.IsValid)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Occured)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This way you avoid code dublication and somewhat follow good practices.