# EntityLinq with Func<> as a parameter works only once

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Sitting some hours and trying to fix ended with no result, may be someone knows how to do it.

**Problem:**
While using [EntityLinq](https://entitylinq.com/) and Func<> as a parameter for WHERE i faced the problem, that first query is working just as i want, but all another, after that first, does not update actionId and all the time function returns the same output.

`(act) => act.StageActionId == stageActionId` acts as stageActionId is the same for any further requests.

**Code snippet:**

```
 public async Task<StageAction> GetActionByIdAsync(string stageActionId)
        {
            var actions = await GetStageActions((act) => act.StageActionId == stageActionId).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            return actions.Where(a => a.ParentAction == null).FirstOrDefault();
        }


private IQueryable<StageAction> GetStageActions(Func<StageAction, bool> rootWhere)
        {
            var query = _context.StageActions.Query(() =>
            {
                var subQuery = SubQuery((StageAction rootActions, StageAction childActions) =>
                {
                    var r = SELECT(rootActions);
                    FROM(rootActions);
                    WHERE(rootWhere(rootActions));

                    UNION_ALL();

                    var act = r.Current();

                    SELECT(childActions);
                    FROM(childActions).JOIN(act).ON(childActions.ParentActionId == act.StageActionId);

                    return r;
                });

                WITH(RECURSIVE(subQuery));

                var result = SELECT(subQuery);
                FROM(subQuery);

                return result;
            });

            return query.AsNoTracking().Include(a => a.ChildActions).Include(a => a.ActionData);
        }
```

**EF Core output [for all 2+ requests p0 is the same]:**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[p0='ee20c449-7312-4c56-a48b-bb82e9e56010'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT s."StageActionId", s."ByAdmin", s."CreatedAt", s."EventStageId", s."ParentActionId", s."Type", s0."StageActionId", s0."ByAdmin", s0."CreatedAt", s0."EventStageId", s0."ParentActionId", s0."Type", s1."ActionDataId", s1."Key", s1."StageActionId", s1."Value"
FROM (
    WITH RECURSIVE q0  AS 
    (SELECT t0.*
    FROM "StageActions" AS t0
    WHERE (t0."StageActionId" = @p0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM "StageActions" AS t1  INNER JOIN q0 AS t2  ON (t1."ParentActionId" = t2."StageActionId"))
    SELECT q0.*
    FROM q0
) AS s
LEFT JOIN "StageActions" AS s0 ON s."StageActionId" = s0."ParentActionId"
LEFT JOIN "StageActionData" AS s1 ON s."StageActionId" = s1."StageActionId"
ORDER BY s."StageActionId", s0."StageActionId", s1."ActionDataId"
```

**What i have already tried:**

1. Try AsNoTracking() because i was thinking caching can be the problem.
2. Try to not to send Func<> as a parameter but by the class field.
3. If i implement the Func<> in `WHERE()` func it works as expected. Means:
   `WHERE(rootActions.StageActionId == stageActionId)` and stageActionId is being sent as a parameter for `GetStageActions()`.

**Why i wanna implement this:**
I have some functions(all differs only by `WHERE()`) and wanna centralize logic but not to write the same code multiple times.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Do query without WHERE and get results.  Then check if the  actionId that you are trying to update is in the results.  You may need to use INSERT if value is not in database.  What database are you using?

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for you interest! I'm sure value is in database [PostgreSql] because i have verified it with PgAdmin + if i restart the app i will successfully get a desired output [but only this output, if i change an id passing with request nothing happens & i get the same output all the time].

Comment: You can try assigning `stageActionId` to local variable and use that in predicate in `GetActionByIdAsync` function.

Comment: Did you try doing update?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: @user1672994, i have followed yours recommendation & what i have changed: 
`string id = stageActionId;
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(id);
var actions = await GetStageActions((act) => act.StageActionId == id).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();`
Output:
1) 
ee20c449-7312-4c56asdf
...Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[p0='ee20c449-7312-4c56asdf'],
2)
 asdfasdf
...Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[p0='ee20c449-7312-4c56asdf'],

As you can see p0 is the same but ActionStageId is different.

Comment: Before ... is the Debug.WriteLine output and after ... output from ef core

Comment: @jdweng, if i correctly understand you, the answer is `no`. Code is simple as it is, endpoint receive request and simply forward ActionId to the function and then responds to the request initiated by Postman.

Comment: I didn't read all details, but `Func<StageAction, bool>` is something that can't be translated to SQL. It's just a local C# function. I guess what you need is `Expression<Func<StageAction, bool>>` which is a description of a function that can be parsed and translated to SQL.

Comment: Dear @ChristophLütjen, may i ask you to provide some code snippet describing evaluation of this expression. `WHERE()` function expects to get `bool` and when i call `rootWhere.Compile().Invoke(rootAction)` it throws an error: `NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

Comment: I have changed function call to be as simple as possible `((act) => true)`, and at the moment i call `GetStageActions` with  `var actions = await GetStageActions((act) => true).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();`, then in debugger, just before the error, i can see the correct Func<>. There is a screen of error: https://ibb.co/WH4HthR

Comment: To be absolutely correct `WHERE()` expects `Stremx.Linq.Sql.IWhereClause` that extends `IClause`

Comment: @Ignatella - if you want to provide a better answer, feel free to copy / paste from my answer, I'll delete mine in this case.

Comment: Don't you need two equal sign in following : t1."ParentActionId" = t2."StageActionId"

Comment: @jdweng, in sql it is equal to `==`. As i know there is no `==` operator in sql.

Comment: I think the posted code is c# so you need two equal signs. I could be wrong that it is SQL pseudo language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of [EntityLinq](https://entitylinq.com/) library.

In fact you hit a bug with an internal cache inside the lambda parser, which is now fixed in the [3.1.10 version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Streamx.Linq.ExTree/).

So either upgrade it or take the [5.0.2 +](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Streamx.Linq.SQL.EFCore) version of the Streamx.Linq.SQL.EFCore library.

Thank you for taking the time to report problems, please use our [issue tracker](https://github.com/streamx-co/entitylinq) for a faster response.

Comment: Hello, thank You for this very important info. Maybe i have started issue in the wrong repo, but there is the link: https://github.com/streamx-co/try.elinq/issues/9 .
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not tested.

> If i implement the Func<> in WHERE() func it works as expected.

The reason for this, is that `Where()` expects an expression. Not a function. Both look very similar:

```
Func<bool> fn = () => true;
Expression<Func<bool>> expr = () => true;
```

In this example `fn` is a function reference that cannot be translated to SQL. `expr` looks the same, but it's an expression: A "description" of your function, and this can be evaluated and converted to SQL.

Or in your code

```
// Where gets an expression - works
Where((act) => act.StageActionId == stageActionId)

// But...
GetStageActions((act) => act.StageActionId == stageActionId)

// Here you say you expect a function and so rootWhere is a function inside
private IQueryable<StageAction> GetStageActions(Func<StageAction, bool> rootWhere) {...}
```

Solution is to change the signature and "say" that you want an expression:

```
private IQueryable<StageAction> GetStageActions(Expression<Func<StageAction, bool>> rootWhere)
```

Please see also @Ignatella s comment:

> To be absolutely correct WHERE() expects Stremx.Linq.Sql.IWhereClause that extends IClause

It wrote this as an answer because it's impossible to explain in a comment. I didn't test it and I've never worked with EntityLinq.

Comment: Thanks for yours commitment, but can You provide how this should be evaluated in a normal example, not obligatory in entityLinq. As i understand that is a kind of wrapper on delegate & i added it to code, but the problem how to use it further. As you see if I try rootWhere.Compile().Invoke() it throws an error

Comment: If You don't mind and it will not be solved until tomorrow i write a simple minimalistic app to reproduce behaviour to to let try it.

Comment: Have you tested what happens if you simply change the function signature?

Comment: Hmm, if i do smth like this: `private IQueryable<StageAction> GetStageActions(Expression<Func<StageAction, bool>> rootWhere)` and then `WHERE(rootWhere(rootActions));` compiler throws an error: `method name expected` (on WHERE(....) line). So i guess it should be called in some specific way?

Comment: You cannot call an expression it's intended to be passed to DB driver. `WHERE(rootWhere)` would compile and tell the driver to build a condition that reflects your rootWhere function. This links may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337692/entity-framework-filter-expressionfunct-bool, https://coderethinked.com/don-t-use-func-delegate-on-the-ef-entities/

Comment: I'm so sorry for this, may be i do not understand smth very simple but it can not be passed in this way because of the fact, that compilator throws an error: I have tried: `WHERE(rootWhere)`, `WHERE(rootWhere(rootActions))` and etc. error can be like `this: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Evr_Bee.Data.Entities.StageAction, bool>>' to 'bool'`

Comment: Ok, now we have two people involved. The one never worked with EntityLinq (I) and the other tried something and got some errors. That will fail ;-) You now know, that Func<> as parameter will not work, so I'd suggest you create a next version and post it as a new question or add the updated code to your question here.